# Infinite metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\delta)$ where no function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Looking for examples of infinite metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\delta)$ such that no function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Comment: That is not possible to do. There always exists the constant function.

Comment: thats true - then is there is a way to minimize the number of possible continuous functions between the two metric spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by minimize? Given $X$ and $Y$ infinite, there are infinitely many continuous functions between them.

Comment: Some conditions on the spaces $(X,Y)$ ensure that every continuous $f:X \to Y$ is constant. For instance, if $X$ is connected and $Y$ is discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, finding such metric spaces is not possible because you always have the constant function $c : (X,d) \to (Y,d')$

But you can ask for conditions on the metric which makes all possible functions between the two metric spaces continuous. One such example is given in the comments. Another one could be that you let $d$ to be the discrete metric on $X$ (this is the same as giving $X$ the discrete topology), then any function from $X$ to $Y$ is going to be continuous.